# How to get the pre edited value from a dataTable column in Primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

When clicking on the edit button in PrimeFaces I want my listener to get the new value of the column as well as the old one. I am currently only getting the new value:

```
public void onLicenseEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    selectedItemLicense = (ItemLicense) event.getObject();
}
```

This is my xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="licenses" var="license"
    value="#{itemShowView.itemReference.lastVersionItemLicenses}"
    emptyMessage="#{messages['common.emptymessage']}"
    class="itemLicensesTable"
    selection="itemShowView.selectedLicense"
    editable="true">
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@(.itemLicensesTable)" listener="#{itemShowView.onLicenseEdit}"  />
    <f:facet name="header">

    <p:column headerText="#{messages['license.licensenumber']}">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{license.licensePK.licenseNumber}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{license.licensePK.licenseNumber}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    ...

    <p:column>
        <p:rowEditor />
    </p:column>

    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use the `<p:inputText valueChangeListener="#{ ... }">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comment. I modified the code using valueChangeListener. This is my solution:

```
<f:facet name="input">
    <p:inputText value="#{itemLicense.itemLicensePK.licenseNumber}" valueChangeListener="#{itemShowView.onLicenceChange}"/>
</f:facet>
```

and the Java code:

```
private ItemLicense selectedItemLicenseForModification;

...

public void onLicenceChange() {
    selectedItemLicenseForModification = (ItemLicense) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("itemLicense");
}
```